# how to pass multiple classes as arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
public IEnumerable<Project> Get(int id)
    {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Project_BL projbl = new Project_BL();
        dt = projbl.SelectprojectModelBasedProjectID(id);
        var tag = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TAGS
        {


            tag_id = x.Field<int>("tag_id"),
            tag_name = x.Field<string>("tag_name")

            // like wise initialize properties here
        });

        return tag;
    }
```

Here,in `Ienumerable<Project>`,`Project` is a class.I want another class to be added there. Also in `var tag = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Project`,
here also  i want to add multiple class

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: how to implement it in  var tag = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TAGS line also

Answer (score 0):

You can probably define a `ViewModel` and have all your classes type as properties defined and use that viewmovel instead as your return type or argument like

```
public class ResultModel
{
  public Project Project {get; set;}
  public Requirement Requirement {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can re-define your method to be

```
public IEnumerable<ResultModel> Get(int id)
    {
```

Comment: how to implement it in  var tag = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TAGS  also